# Commutators with Hamiltonian of the form $H=\frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, commutator

Consider a one-dimensional problem with a Hamiltonian
\begin{equation*}
H=\frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)
\end{equation*}
where $x$ and $p$ are the position and momentum operators, $m$ is the mass and $V(x)$ the potential. $x$ and $p$ are the canonical position and momentum which satisfy that $[x, p] = i\hbar$. In terms of $p$, $x$, and $V(x)$, what are $[H, p], [H, x], [H, xp]$.

For $[H, p]$:
\begin{gather*}
 [\frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x), p] = \frac{1}{2m}[p^2, p] + [V(x), p] \\
= [V(x), p]
\end{gather*}
For $[H, x]$:
\begin{gather*}
 [\frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x), x] = \frac{1}{2m}[p^2, x] + [V(x), x] \\
= \frac{1}{2m}[p^2, x] = \frac{1}{2m}(p(px)-p(xp)+(px)p-(xp)p) \\
= \frac{1}{2m}(p(px-xp) + (px-xp)p) = \frac{1}{2m}(-p[x,p] - [x,p]p) \\
= \frac{1}{2m}(-p(i\hbar) - (i\hbar)p) = -\frac{i \hbar}{m}p
\end{gather*}
For $[H, xp]$:
\begin{gather*}
 [\frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x), xp] = \frac{1}{2m}(pxp^2 - pxp^2 + p^2xp - xpp^2) + [V(x),xp] \\
= \frac{1}{2m} ((px - xp)p^2 + p(px - xp)p) + [V(x),xp] \\ 
= -\frac{i\hbar}{m}p^2 + V(x)xp - xpV(x) + xV(x)p -xV(x)p \\
= -\frac{i\hbar}{m}p^2 + [V(x), x]p + x[V(x), p] \\
= -\frac{i\hbar}{m}p^2 + x[V(x), p]
\end{gather*}

Is the calculation okay or am I missing something?

Comment: One side note: You can further simplify you first statement by $\propto V'(x)$. Try proving it, is a fun exercise.

Comment: I often wonder if the second commutator has anything to do with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430858/fourier-transform-of-derivative)?

Answer (score 1):

You can check it yourself.  Your three answers reduce to the following by inspection:

$$ \begin{equation} [H,xp] = x[H,p] + p[H,x] \end{equation} $$

There is an identity for commutators as follows:

$$  \begin{equation} [\hat{A}, \hat{B}\hat{C}] = \hat{B}[\hat{A},\hat{C}] + [\hat{A},\hat{B}]\hat{C} \end{equation} $$

The first term on the rhs is ok but the second is not unless *p* commutes with *[H,x]*.  Since *[H,x]* is just a multiple of *p* it does indeed commute and your result checks out.  (Even by inspection, I could have written it down as *[H,x]p* but I chose the other form before looking up the commutator identity!)

The larger point is this: While the pedestrian approach gets you to the right answer for the third commutator, it's a long walk.  Sometimes it's better to take the bus!